# How to limit a datetime input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Im updating a test registration site and need the date of birth to be limited on the client side i.e. person needs to be 18 or over to enroll as a student

```
public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
txtDOB.Text = studentDetails.dateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Is there some way I can limit the calendar input to only allow input from 2000 or before

Comment: Just get current date/year to deduct student's `dateOfBirth` to check whether is him over 18

Comment: You need a custom validation attribute

Comment: Refer [this article](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/07/how-to-implement-custom-user-defined-age-range-validation-mvc4.html) for an example

Comment: You might want to test the code in an (incorrect) answer before accepting it!

Answer (score 2):

You can write custom attribute,

```
public class DateTimeRangeAtt : RangeAttribute
    {
        public DateTimeRangeAtt()
          : base(typeof(DateTime),
                new DateTime(1, 1, 1920).ToShortDateString(),
                new DateTime(1, 1, DateTime.Now.Year-18).ToShortDateString())
        { }
    }

[DateTimeRangeAtt]
public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: There are people of over a hundred years old. While the chance is small they're going to register with the OP's app, why impose such arbitrary limits? Just allow for 150 years of age.

Comment: @CodeCaster 150years old registering for universities. sure.

Comment: First you have not taken into account the date and month of the users birthday. Second it does nothing unless the attribute is registered. Third, it does not work for client side validation

Comment: @Valkyriee that's ageism. Why wouldn't 150 year old people want to enroll in a course, for knitting or whatever? All jokes aside, you're missing the point though. Why should an answer impose an unspecified limit?

Comment: The question was how to limit the date field. At what age people can register or it's not my job to check the birth dates of the users

Answer (score -1):

You can use DataAnnotations for this

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: A `[DisplayFormat]` has nothing at all to do with validating a date is in a certain range

Comment: What on earth has that link to do with your answer